# Custom form (Web App) to send value and use it with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a custom form in order to send one value (ID) and below of the form see the search result based on the input field.

For example: Complete the form and below see the search result in a DataBase (Google Sheets)

[image: DataBase - Google Sheets]

[image: Request Form]

I saw some examples but I don't know how to get the value of the input field and use it with the Google Apps Script code (in order to search the ID in the rows).

Here some code I was trying:
code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}


function obtenerId() {
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var idtest='Juan';
  return messageSecret_(idtest);
}

function messageSecret_(urldoc) {
  return 'test'+urldoc;
}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onSuccess(balance) {
        var div = document.getElementById('output');
        var idtest = document.getElementById('ingresoid').value;
        div.innerHTML = balance+' '+idtest;
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!--Modificar texto de la aplicación -->
    <p style="margin-bottom: 16px; font-family: 'Verdana regular'; font-size: 16px;color: #727277;line-height: 16px;text-align: justify;">Ingrese ID:
    <br><br></p>
    <input type="textbox" id="ingresoid" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar respuesta" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .obtenerId();" style="background-color:#C1D72E;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;color: #fff; border-color: #C1D72E;"
      /><br>
      <br>
      
      <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should include your code directly in your post.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added my code.

Comment: You need to use the `SpreadsheetApp` class, get the spreadsheet by ID, and then get the sheet tab, then get a range, then set the value in the range.  [Link to Get Sheet by Name](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) And:  [Link to Get Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) And also: [Set Value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))

Comment: Thanks, but how is possible to pass the value of the input field to the Google Apps Script section. That's my main problem since I have the value in html section, but it doesn't exist in GAS section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<input type="textbox" id="ingresoid" size="20">
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Enviar respuesta" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
      .obtenerId();" style="background-color:#C1D72E;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;color: #fff; border-color: #C1D72E;"
  /><br>
```

#### To:

```
<form> <!-- Added -->
    <input type="textbox" id="ingresoid" size="20" name="sample"> <!-- Modified -->
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Enviar respuesta" onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .obtenerId(this.parentNode);" style="background-color:#C1D72E;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;color: #fff; border-color: #C1D72E;"
      /><br>  <!-- Modified -->
</form> <!-- Added -->
```

After modified, the inputted value can be retrieved at GAS side as follows.

```
function obtenerId(e) {
  var value = e.sample;
}
```

Comment: Very very helpful, I can do it with your sample. Thank you!

Comment: @user2946433 Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.